# Jgrid Save cell on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

HI,
I am using `afterSaveCell` that fires if we modifies the cell then it get fires.

My scenario is that i m doing batch update to the database on save change button. But when user edit the cell and got to the other cell then i log the modification in a array.

But if user edit the cell and click on the Save Change button the cell focus not get lost (Still in edit mode) and `afterSaveCell` not get fired.

IS there any way to fire the Save the cell on buttojn click so that `afterSaveCell` get fires.

Please, Help..
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [saveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) method. This method has `iRow` and `iCol` as a parameters. To know the this parameters for the current editable cell you can add [afterEditCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) to the grid. So you save last values of `iRow` and `iCol` in a variable outside of jqGrid and use there inside of on click event on "Save Change" button where you call [saveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) with these parameters.

Comment: Ok..i will keep in Mind..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// This worked Perfectly fine for me, hope will work for you as well.
var selectedCellId;
    var $gridTableObj = $('#jqGridTable');
    $gridTableObj.jqGrid({
        datatype : "jsonstring",
        datastr : gridJSON,
        height : ($(window).height() - 110),
        width : ($(window).width() - 80),
        gridview : true,
        loadonce : false,
        colNames : columnNames,
        colModel : columnModel,
        rowNum : gridJSON.length,
        viewrecords : true,
        subGrid : false,
        autoheight : true,
        autowidth : false,
        shrinkToFit : true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
        cellEdit : true,
        jsonReader : {
            root : "rows",
            repeatitems : false
        },
        onCellSelect : function(id, cellidx, cellvalue) { // use this event to capture edited cellID
            selectedCellId = cellidx; // save the cellId to a variable
        },
        loadComplete : function(data) {
            jQuery("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("oddRow");
            jQuery("tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("evenRow");
        }
    });
```

// Attach on click event jqgrid "saveCell" to save the cell.

```
var gridCellWasClicked = false;
window.parent.document.body.onclick = saveEditedCell; // attach to parent window if any
document.body.onclick = saveEditedCell; // attach to current document.
function saveEditedCell(evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);
    var isCellClicked = $gridTableObj.find(target).length; // check if click is inside jqgrid
    if(gridCellWasClicked && !isCellClicked) // check if a valid click
        {
        var rowid = $gridTableObj.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    $gridTableObj.jqGrid("saveCell", rowid, selectedCellId);
    gridCellWasClicked = false;
    }
    if(isCellClicked){
        gridCellWasClicked = true; // flat to check if there is a cell been edited.
    }
};
```