# How can I calculate a Total column on client side using jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to implement a simple spreadsheet using jqGrid. These are the grid columns:

`ID | Name | LastName | Data1 | Data2 | Total` (Total would be Data1 + Data2)

My javascript code looks like this:

```
$(function() {    
 var lastsel;

        jQuery("#my_excel_grid").jqGrid({

            url:'data_excel.php',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['id','name', 'lastname', 'data1','data2','total'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:55, sortable:false},
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:90},
                {name:'lastname',index:'lastname', width:100},
                {name:'data1',index:'data1', width:80, align:"right", editable:true},
                {name:'data2',index:'data2', width:80, align:"right", editable:true},       
                {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
                             {
                                 // Harcoded index won't work in the real life excel grid
                                 //        since the columns will be populated dynamically
                                 return parseInt(rowObject[3]) + parseInt(rowObject[4]);
                              }
                },      
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: '#my_excel_pager',
            sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption:"Excel",          
            editurl:"data_excel.php?op=edit",          

            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                      jQuery('#my_excel_grid').restoreRow(lastsel);
                      jQuery('#my_excel_grid').editRow(id, true);
                      lastsel = id;
                    }
                  },

             beforeSubmitCell: function(rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) { alert("beforeSubmitCell"); },
             afterSaveCell: function (rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) { alert("afterSaveCell"); },

        }); });
```

The issue I'm having is that *beforeSubmitCell* and *afterSaveCell* are not been called (I don't get the alerts messages), so I can't write the new value in the Total column. By the way the *editurl* url is dummy, it's not returning anything (I've also tried setting 'clientArray' with no success).

So, **how can I calculate the Total column on client side?**

FYI: The idea is to save the grid using an [external "Save" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828261/jgrid-save-cell-on-button-click) and also populate the columns dynamically as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867459/dynamic-population-of-jqgrid-colmodel-and-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid have three [editing modes](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#editing) which you can use: [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing), [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) and [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). If you use [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) and [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#restorerow) it means that you use [the inline editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing). The [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) and [beforeSubmitCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) events are used only in case of cell editing mode.

So what you need to do is

1. to remove the unused `beforeSubmitCell` and `beforeSubmitCell` events from the jqGrid definition.
2. to add additional parameters in the call of editRow. You need to use the [aftersavefunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) parameter. Instead of `jQuery('#my_excel_grid').editRow(id, true);` you can use `jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', {}, function(rowid,issuccess){alert(rowid);});`

Comment: thanks, it worked! btw, you've repeated beforeSubmitCell in 1

Comment: @epzee: You are welcome! The  event names which should be removed are `afterSaveCell` and `beforeSubmitCell` (both from the cell editing)